# Running a local React build in WKWebView

Tags: reactjs, swift, xcode

I am trying to run a local React build in a WKWebview but without success. I have referred to various other posts but still cannot get it to work. I am using Xcode 13, Swift 5 and main code so far:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
       webView.uiDelegate = self
       webView.navigationDelegate = self
       webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
    
       let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html", subdirectory: "WebPocket")!
       webView.loadFileURL(url, allowingReadAccessTo: url)
       let request = URLRequest(url: url)
       webView.load(request)
   }

   override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
       get {
           return true
       }
   }

}
```

I have also added this to the plist file

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>127.0.0.1</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

I know that there isn't an issue with the code itself in general, as I can load a static, local html file without any issues. Any help would be greatly appreciated